# How can I create a basic human readable plain text representation of XHTML using Java?

Tags: java, html, xhtml, plaintext

Given some simple XHTML, I'd like to create a human readable plain text version of it.  This would involve removing all HTML tags, but adding or preserving some whitespace.

For example, this input:

```
<div>
<p>This is some text, some is <b>bold</b>.</p>
<ul>
  <li>Point one</li>
  <li>Point two</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

would become:

```
"This is some text, some is bold. Point one Point two"
```

(commas between the LIs would be ideal... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jericho HTML Parser. You can either strip all the tags or call on a "renderer" class that tries to mimick the look (eg your bulleted lists would be tabbed)

Comment: That look promising, could I just use the TextExtractor? http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html

Comment: Thanks, that works well, I'm using the Renderer as you suggested: http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/RenderToText.java

Comment: Great. The Text Extractor is good for just getting the words. The Renderer can produce a "fake HTML" text rep. So both have their uses.